# I want specific set of records at the top regardless of the sorting in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

Following function returns all the players in 2-D array format. Below is the function:-

```
public function get_football_players($type = FOOTBALL_TEXT, $filter = '', $start = '', $limit = '', $player = '') {
        $this->db->select('tblmarkets_football.*, tblmarkets.symbol, tblmarkets.type');
        $this->db->from('tblmarkets_football');
        $this->db->join('tblmarkets','tblmarkets.id = tblmarkets_football.market_id','left');
        if($type != ''){
            $this->db->where('type', $type);
        }
        $this->db->where('active', 1);
        switch ($filter) {
            case 'forward':
                $this->db->where('position', 'Forward');
                break;
            case 'midfielders':
                $this->db->where('position', 'Midfielder');
                break;
            case 'defenders':
                $this->db->where('position', 'Defender');
                break;
            case 'goalkeepers':
                $this->db->where('position', 'Goalkeeper');
                break;
            case 'highest_price':
            case 'lowest_price':
                $tmp = $this->external_api_model->get_filtered_football_pairs($limit, $start, $filter);
                $players = json_decode($tmp, true);
                $this->db->where_in('symbol', $players);
                break;
        }
        if($player != ''){
            $this->db->like('tblmarkets_football.name', $player);
        }
        if($filter != 'highest_price' && $filter != 'lowest_price'){
            $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
         }
        $result = $this->db->get()->result();
        return $result;
    }
```

when someone apply the highest price filter then **get_filtered_football_pairs** api returns all the players in array format. I want all those players to be shown at the top, in the order I have received. `$players` have all the player names. currently they are shown randomly.

Any help will be appreciated. thanks in advance.

**Edit**

$players will look like below:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => paul-pogba
    [1] => neymar
    [2] => kylian-mbappé
    [3] => lionel-messi
    [4] => jadon-sancho
    [5] => eden-hazard
    [6] => marcus-rashford
    [7] => mohamed-salah
    [8] => harry-kane
    [9] => vinicius-junior
    [10] => callum-hudson-odoi
    [11] => raheem-sterling
    [12] => ousmane-dembele
    [13] => anthony-martial
    [14] => paulo-dybala
    [15] => gareth-bale
    [16] => joshua-kimmich
    [17] => cristiano-ronaldo
    [18] => kai-havertz
    [19] => leroy-sané
)
```

I want in that order that means first it will show paul-pogba then neymar and so on like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested, but the logic is that you escape the elements in the `$player` array, then apply the preferential treatment to the qualifying `symbol` values, then provide the secondary sort order as `symbol` ascending (otherwise just leave things random after separating the players from the non-players.

```
case 'highest_price':
case 'lowest_price':
    $tmp = $this->external_api_model->get_filtered_football_pairs($limit, $start, $filter);
    $players = json_decode($tmp, true);
    $this->db->where_in('symbol', $players);
    foreach ($players as &$p) {
        $p = "'" . $this->db->escape_str($p) . "'";
    }
    $this->db->order_by("IF(FIELD(symbol," . implode(",", $players) . ")=0,1,0),
                         FIELD(symbol," . implode(",", $players) . ")");
    break;
```

Here is a db-fiddle demonstration displaying how the ordering will be executed: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9yxTo3nEHCu9vLPW6MELy3/1

To aid in the comprehension of my technique: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/109126/157408

To explain the `0,1` part of the clause...

It separates the `$players` before the non-`$players`. All of the `$players` will be in the `0` group and the non-`$players` will be in the `1` group. Then the secondary sorting will put the `$players` in your preferred order (breaking the `0` ties).

---

p.s. I don't think it is sensible to make the default values for `$start` and `$limit` empty strings -- numeric values seems better suited.

I generally try to stay away from switch blocks because I find that too verbose.  Another style might look like this (depending on your expected input and logical requirements, you may be able to boil it down further):

```
if (in_array($filter, ['forward', 'midfielders', 'defenders', 'goalkeepers'])) {
    $this->db->where('position', ucfirst(rtrim($filter, 's')));
}

if (in_array($filter, ['highest_price', 'lowest_price'])) {
    $tmp = $this->external_api_model->get_filtered_football_pairs($limit, $start, $filter);
    $players = json_decode($tmp, true);
    $this->db->where_in('symbol', $players);
    foreach ($players as &$p) {
        $p = "'" . $this->db->escape_str($p) . "'";
    }
    $this->db->order_by("IF(FIELD(symbol," . implode(",", $players) . ")=0,1,0),
                         FIELD(symbol," . implode(",", $players) . ")");
} else {
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
}

if ($player != '') {
    $this->db->like('tblmarkets_football.name', $player);
}
```

Comment: I'm actually getting **Call to undefined function escape_str()** error

Comment: actually your first answer is not showing record in that order. check the Edit portion of my question.

Comment: what is the use of 0,1 at the end the query

Comment: I have edited my answer to include my comments.  Let's purge the comments now.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that somewhere in your tables there's a `price` field, all you'd need to do is:

```
case 'highest_price':
$tmp = $this->external_api_model->get_filtered_football_pairs($limit, $start, $filter);
$players = json_decode($tmp, true);
$this->db->where_in('symbol', $players);
$this->db->order_by('your_price_field', 'DESC');
break;

case 'lowest_price':
$tmp = $this->external_api_model->get_filtered_football_pairs($limit, $start, $filter);
$players = json_decode($tmp, true);
$this->db->where_in('symbol', $players);
$this->db->order_by('your_price_field', 'ASC');
break;
```

An alternative way to do this would be to have different methods in your model which get called depending on the case found by the `switch` but "filtering" by price requires nothing more than an `order_by` query builder statement

Comment: I donot have a price field that's the problem.

Comment: How could you possibly filter by price if you don't have the price for each player? It would be the equivalent of sorting the ages of a group of Stackoverflowers based on nothing more than their last names. You'd need to add a `price` field for each player, populate those fields and then sort using that field

Comment: actually price comes from the api and it is stored in the cache from there we get in based on symbol. Since it's unique and price is also updated using sockets so it was not possible to hit the database all the time because it will slow down the database.